# Peer-to-Peer (w/ iPhones)?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, p2p, bonjour, iphone-sdk-3.2

Is it possible to have your app accept "ALL" Peer-to-Peer connections, say via settings?

I prefer the option of allowing users to "always accept bonjour connections for myApp, automatically" or "accept bonjour connections each time".  I prefer not to have my app ask "Do you want to accept a connection" each time the user is using my app.

Or is there a way around this given my scenario (e.g. XMPP)?  I need my app to pass over a small amount of data, just a string or string with an image and then disconnect forever. I assume to do this requires both apps to be running and on the same network, correct?

What I am trying to avoid is the ugly blue call to action pop-ups, "Join network", "Accept connection", etc...

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GameKit, it provides simple api for p2p over wifi and bluetooth. There's even [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918) in the iOS Dev Center.

Comment: Yeah, I know about Gamekit, but I would rather not have to use those. I don't want to show a blue pop-up.

Comment: You don't have to show a popup, you can create a [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) programatically.